# Corresponding list value and index in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list and I know the maximum value of that list by using `Max[list]`. The thing is I want to find out the index number of this list that corresponds to this value. For example:

```
list={9999,2,3,4,5,....,1}
Max[list]
(*9999*)
c= f[Max[list]]
```

where the function `f` gives me the index of `list` that corresponds to the value `Max[list]` which is `9000` in this case. Maybe using `Pick` somehow. Since I am dealing with frequency spectrum, and I know that the maximum is near a low frequency, I would like for the function to just check the first few or so instead of all elements in `list`.

Comment: Have you seen `Position[]`?

Comment: @J.M. I just did! Thanks! Anyone interested: `f = {Max[#], Flatten[Position[#, Max[#]]][[1]]} &;` where the output is in the form `(***{ max value, index in list} ***)`

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
First@Flatten@Position[#, Max[#]] &@list
```

alternative:

```
Last@Ordering[list]
```

Comment: Nice! Very similar implementation. I have been using Mathematica for well over a year now on and off and now only getting use to the `Function` and `#&` usage. I have been seeing a lot people on here using this `@` I imagine its to do more than one function at a time. See my comment as well.

Comment: The second argument of `Ordering[]` is quite convenient: `Ordering[list, -1]`.

Comment: yes it took me some time to get a hang of the symbols too. The learning curve was steep i believe. &@ is as if you are saying apply a function on an argument, say (func &) and apply on something i.e. func&@something. And (Last@something) for instance means the same as Last[something ]

Comment: @J.M. Spot on. I might change my code to use `Ordering` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {10, 9999, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1};
```

Using `PositionLargest` (new in 13.2)

```
PositionLargest[list]
```

{2}

Positions of the 2 largest values

```
PositionLargest[list, 2]
```

{{2}, {1}}

With `TakeLargest` (new in 10.1) we can get positions and elements in
one go:

```
TakeLargest[list -> {"Index", "Element"}, 2]
```

{{2, 9999}, {1, 10}}

Answer (score 1):

Grabbing the @eldo's list and using `MaximalBy`:

```
list = {10, 9999, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1};

List @@@ MaximalBy[Rule @@@ Thread@{Range[Length@#], #} &@list, Last]

(*{{2, 9999}}*)
```

As with `TakeLargest, with` MaximalBy we can obtain more positions and elements:

```
List @@@ MaximalBy[Rule @@@ Thread@{Range[Length@#], #} &@list, Last, 2]

(*{{2, 9999}, {1, 10}}*)
```